# C#/.NET Future Relative Timestamps?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timestamp

I'm looking for some way to make a relative text timestamp but using future instead of past (not "2 days ago" but "in 2 days").

I'm making a personal task manager for my personal usages and I'd like it to tell me "this task is due in 2 days". But I can't seem to find nothing to convert a `DateTime` to that kind of timestamp.

Comment: Are you looking for an already existing library, or a way to do it yourself? I'm not sure what might already be out there, but you should be able to do this fairly simply with a method that does futureTimeStamp.Subtract(DateTime.Now) to get a TimeSpan, and then using the Days/Hours/Minutes etc. properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on all the replies I finally made one myself which meets all my requierements:

```
public static string RemainingTimeBeforeDateTime(DateTime dateTime, int level = 1)
{
    int howDeep = 0;
    string result = "";

    TimeSpan dueDuration = dateTime - DateTime.Now;

    double days = dueDuration.Days;
    double hours = dueDuration.Hours;
    double minutes = dueDuration.Minutes;

    if (days > 0)
    {
        howDeep++;
        result = days + "d ";
    }

    if (((howDeep != level) && (days != 0)) || ((days == 0) && (hours > 0)))
    {
        howDeep++;
        result = result + hours + "h ";
    }

    if (((howDeep != level) && (hours != 0)) || ((hours == 0) && (minutes > 0)))
    {
        result = result + minutes + "m ";
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work for you?...

```
DateTime myTask = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2.0);
```

### Update

As Reed pointed out in the comment box below, the OP might also be looking for a way to tell the time until the task is due or the time the task has been past due. I think something like this will work (note that I have not compiled this code, but it should give you a good idea):

```
public string PrintTaskDueTime(DateTime taskTime, DateTime currTime)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    TimeSpan timeDiff = TimeSpan.Zero;
    if(taskTime > currTime)
    {
        timeDiff = taskTime-currTime;
        result = String.Format("Your task is due in {0} days and {1} hours.", timeDiff.TotalDays, timeDiff.Hours);
    }
    else if(taskTime == currTime)
    {
        result = "Your task is due now!";
    }
    else
    {
        timeDiff = currTime-taskTime;
        result = String.Format("Your task is {0} days and {1} hours past due!", timeDiff.TotalDays, timeDiff.Hours);
    }

    return result;
}
```

So just call it by specifying the task time and the current time: `PrintTimeDiff(taskTime, DateTime.Now);`

I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't quite think that's what the OP is after (though I may be wrong...) I think he's after how to determine how far out that DateTime actually is...

Answer (score 2):

If you have the date that it's due in a `DateTime`, then you can use a `TimeSpan` to get the time until due.  For example:

```
TimeSpan dueDuration = dueDate - DateTime.Now;

Console.WriteLine("Due in {0} days and {1} hours.", dueDuration.TotalDays, dueDurations.Hours);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **DateTime** type is used to represent specific points in time. For example, **DateTime.Now**.

The **TimeSpan** is used to represent specific durations of time. For example, **TimeSpan.FromDays(2)**.

There are operator overloads that allow them to interact nicely with one another, For example,

```
DateTime dueDate = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

A future relative timestamp is just like a past, but with the sign different.

```
string RelativeTime(DateTime when)
{
     TimeSpan diff = when - DateTime.Now;
     var minutes = (int) diff.TotalMinutes;
     if (minutes == 1)
          return "A minute from now";

     if (minute == 2)
          return "In a couple minutes";

     if (minutes < 10)
          return "In not 10 minutes";

     if (minutes < 40)
          return "In about half an hour";

     /*  etc   */

}
```

The / * etc * /  part is tedious and requires creativity, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something I put together based on James' answer. Supports past, present, and future :)

Note: It can probably be shortened a bit more.

```
public static string RelativeTime(DateTime Date, string NowText = "Now")
{
    const int SECOND = 1;
    const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
    const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
    const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

    TimeSpan TimeSpan;
    double delta = 0d;

    //It's in the future
    if (Date > DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
        TimeSpan = new TimeSpan(Date.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks);
        delta = Math.Abs(TimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
        if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
        {
            if (TimeSpan.Seconds == 0)
                return NowText;
            else
                return TimeSpan.Seconds == 1 ? "A second from now" : TimeSpan.Seconds + " seconds from now";
        }
        if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
            return "A minute from now";
        if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
            return TimeSpan.Minutes + " minutes from now";
        if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
            return "An hour from now";
        if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
            return TimeSpan.Hours + " hours from now";
        if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
            return "Tomorrow";
        if (delta < 30 * DAY)
            return TimeSpan.Days + " days from now";
        if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
        {
            int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)TimeSpan.Days / 30));
            return months <= 1 ? "A month from now" : months + " months from now";
        }
        else
        {
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)TimeSpan.Days / 365));
            return years <= 1 ? "A year from now" : years + " years from now";
        }
    }
    //It's in the past
    else if (Date < DateTime.UtcNow)
    {
        TimeSpan = new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - Date.Ticks);
        delta = Math.Abs(TimeSpan.TotalSeconds);
        if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
        {
            if (TimeSpan.Seconds == 0)
                return NowText;
            else
                return TimeSpan.Seconds == 1 ? "A second ago" : TimeSpan.Seconds + " seconds ago";
        }
        if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
            return "A minute ago";
        if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
            return TimeSpan.Minutes + " minutes ago";
        if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
            return "An hour ago";
        if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
            return TimeSpan.Hours + " hours ago";
        if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
            return "Yesterday";
        if (delta < 30 * DAY)
            return TimeSpan.Days + " days ago";
        if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
        {
            int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)TimeSpan.Days / 30));
            return months <= 1 ? "A month ago" : months + " months ago";
        }
        else
        {
            int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)TimeSpan.Days / 365));
            return years <= 1 ? "A year ago" : years + " years ago";
        }
    }
    //It's now
    else
        return NowText;
}
```